# Viewing pandas dataframe raises SettingWithCopyWarning in interactive session

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I run into a strange situation that I didn't have an explanation for it at all. Let's start by having a simple pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, -1]})
```

say I want to select only postive rows to a dataframe and then modify the selected/filtered dataframe,

```
b = a[a['A'] > 0]
```

then when I modify `b` the pandas SettingWithCopyWarning will be raised, and it is expected since `b` is just a *view* of `a`:

```
b['B'] = -999
```

warning is raised:

```
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

but it will be okay when I overwrite the variable `a`:

```
a = a[a['A'] > 0]
a['B'] = -999
```

this will *NOT* raise warning and a simple `id()` check also shows this `a` now is a completely different object now. However, in an *interactive* session (notebook, ipython or python shell), this still raises the warning if you *VIEWED* the variable, that is:
in one cell you do:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, -1]})
a
```

which will display nicely:

```
Out[4]:
   A
0  1
1  1
2 -1
```

then in next cell (or line, in ipython or python shell), you do the same thing:

```
a = a[a['A'] > 0]
a['B'] = -999
```

the warning is *raised*:

```
ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

Why would this simple *viewing* action make this difference? from what I understood it should not raise this warning (especially if you check with `id()` too, `a` became a new object with different `id` value). The second question is, is this the only way for this kind of behavior to happen?

Comment: My guess is that Pandas is trying to figure out if the original 'a' dataframe is still in use.  If it's not in use, then the warning is redundant, because there's no original to change. I'd guess that viewing the dataframe causes Jupyter to keep a reference to it.

Comment: @NickODell thanks for the suggestion. I tried using `sys.getrefcount(a)` to look at `a`'s reference count, in both cases the ref count is same which is 2. Perhaps the pandas has its own counter somehow? if so any way we can look at it? a quick google search didn't show anything

Comment: It looks like this is where the warning is emitted: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/50ae0bfc383b5cefa39e82c0446dce11d4ce10e9/pandas/core/generic.py#L3857 Looks like it checks the internal `_is_copy` attribute of the dataframe, then does some additional logic to check if anything holds a reference to it (excluding _is_copy itself, because that is only a weakref.) Not sure I understand what it's doing.